# FATAL: cannot open /dev/ttyAMA0: Permission denied

Tags: bluetooth

When I want to use `hc-05` I get the error below. What can I do to solve this?

> FATAL: cannot open `/dev/ttyAMA0`: Permission denied

Comment: You can (for the moment) continue to use `/dev/ttyAMA0` on Pi2 and earlier, but should use `/dev/serial0` which is the new device independent default serial port.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo` with the command. See `man sudo` for a complete explanation of its purpose and usage:

> `sudo` allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified by the security policy.

Device nodes are often restricted for superuser access.

Note that if the command involves redirection (`>` or `<`) it may still not work.  E.g.,

```
sudo echo "123" > /dev/ttyAMA0
```

Will fail.